# Why subscript is out of bounds during for loops execution?

Tags: r, for-loop

In my script is it possible to get `d[[x]]` "empty". I tried to do it with `else`, but it does not work.

How to write `else` so that it can give a result of checking zero?

```
for (x in 1:licznik3) 
{
  if(a[[x]] > d[[x]]) 
  {
    out3[[x]] <- wspolne3[[x]]
  }
  else (a[[x]] < d[[x]]) 
  {
    out3[[x]] <- NA

  }
}
```

variables:

```
> a
 [1] 0.1
> d
numeric(0)
> licznik3
[1] 16
```

> Error in d[[x]] : subscript out of bounds

Example:

I have 3 loops.

If `a[[x]]` is greater than `d[[x]]`

this value goes to `out3`

and the next loop checks a similar condition.

My problem is that in the second loop (shown code) `d[[x]]` can be empty (in the previous loop no value was greater than `a[[x]]`)

Then we have how

```
> a
  [1] 0.1
> d
numeric (0)
```

Comment: no one can help you if you don't provide a working example, where vectors `licznik3` and `wspolne3` are unambiguous.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is hard to figure out what you are asking. For example, the phrase "it does not go out" has no clear meaning. What is "it" and what does it mean for "it" to fail to "go out"?

Comment: example in edited post

Comment: Your example helps some, but it is still not at all clear what the expected output is. What is supposed to happen if `d[[x]]` is undefined? Why not simply check `d` *before* the loop and not execute the loop if `d` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Just add additional check that your counter aka licznik3 ;) would not exceed length of vector `d`. If it exceeds `break` `for`-loop.

```
a <- 1:10
licznik3 <- 7
out3 <- rep_along(a, NA)
wspolne3 <- 2:12
d <- -c(1, 4, 2)

for (x in 1:licznik3) {
  if (x > length(d)) {
    break
  }

  if (a[[x]] > d[[x]]) {
    out3[[x]] <- wspolne3[[x]]
  } else {
    out3[[x]] <- NA
  }
}

out3
```